# Previous splash screen shows for a second in IONIC app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I just created an ionic app and previously I added a splash screen and that was working fine. Now I added another splash screen in resources using the command

`ionic Cordova resources ios --splash`

now when I checked every splash screen in updated.

After I compiled and build the iOS app and tested it shows the previous Splashscreen for a second and then updated splash screen is shown and moved to my home screen.

I removed the platform and added again. reupdated with new splash screen still, this issue exists! WHy does this happen?

Comment: try using the --force option to ensure the new splash screen is created for all resolutions

`ionic cordova resources -s --force`

Comment: All the resources are updated.I can see that in the splash images in splash folder updated to new. Anyways let me try with --force

Comment: and you have then rebuild your xcode project? `ionic cordova build ios`

Comment: Yes.. i run `ionic cordova build ios --prod`

Comment: @jaaaawn I tried --force.. still old splashcreen is shown for a second before the new splashscreen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally got the solution.

1. Delete your app from the device
2. Power down the device
3. Power up the device, install and launch the app.

It's not my app issue. I think it wont happen in production version.

Comment: On my iPhone 6s (12.3) its still showing a previously cached splash screen image (its huge, warping the image and cut off image sides along screen edge) - that image doesn't even exist in the app anymore.  I deleted the app, rebooted the phone, reinstalled the app but its still showing - after the wrong big/skewed one shows it then shows the correct image properly sized.  I can't get rid of the cached one.

Comment: It actually worked for React native as well.

Answer (score 3):

iOS devices first show a launch image and then the actual splash image from the plugin. The image is the same, so you won't notice this.

But the launch image is cached by the devices and simulators, so if you change the splash image, it will still show the old launch image.

The solution is just to delete the app (no need to power off and on again), and it won't happen in production versions.

Comment: i had to power off and on again. Deleting and reinstalling without restart the device didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

For all future developers facing this issue since I see no post with the correct solution:

There is a folder that for me was called res/screen/ios which contained the old splash screen and I never replaced that file. Removing the file in that folder from my application, adding the new image in that folder, and changing the name of the new image to 'Default@2x~universal~anyany.png' resolved this issue.

Comment: This does need to happen in order for this to work properly but I know I had already done this and needed to also power down the app first to clear the device cache for the splash screen.